# Populate a drop down list after another list has made it's selection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am working on a ASP.Net Project and have populated a list called categories, once this list has made a selection i would like the next list titled sub categories to populate with possible selections.

The first list is populated during the page load where i bind the list to a data table.

I have written a function to bind the next list and have given it a parameter, how ever i can't get the function to call.

```
<td valign="top">
 <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="ddRequestCategory" enableviewstate="False" runat="server" id="lblCategories" meta:resourcekey="lblResCategories" CssClass="FormLabel"  />
</td>
<td align="left" valign="top">
 <ICCM:ICCMDropdownlist style="width:185px;" runat="server" ID="ddRequestCategory" CssClass="iccmdropdown" TabIndex="1" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddCategorySelectChange"/>
</td> 

public void ddCategorySelectChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string categories;
   categories = ddRequestCategory.SelectedItem.ToString();
   GetSubCategories(categories );

}
```

---

When selecting the Drop down the code never enters the ddCategorySelectChange ???

Comment: first DropDown's item select and second DropDown's item bind depend on first's selected item ?

Comment: In Ajax or Regular Post back or what you are trying? show us your code

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler and inside that call your function to load data to subcategories `dropdownlist` :

```
  protected void drpCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadDrpSubCategory();
    }

 private void LoadDrpSubCategory()
    {
        List<SubCategory> list_SubCategory = new List<SubCategory>();
        Guid Id_Category = Guid.Parse(drpCategory.SelectedValue);
        list_SubCategory = //write code to get data;

        drpSubCategory.DataValueField = "Id";
        drpSubCategory.DataTextField = "TFName";
        drpSubCategory.DataSource = list_SubCategory;
        drpSubCategory.DataBind();

    }
```

and your `.aspx` code would look like :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpCategory" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpCategory_SelectedIndexChanged" >
```

note that in your .aspx code It's really important to set `AutoPostBack="true"`

Comment: It's also worth noting the important of AutoPostBack="true". There are many questions on the internet of dropdown lists behaving unexpectedly, and a lot of the time the solution is to ensure AutoPostBack is set to true.

Comment: @DeeMac You are on  ,I edited my answear and added the point you said .

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using listbox. Add below event to listbox. From this event you can bind the second listbox.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lst" runat="server"AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lst_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>

  protected void lst_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Comment: I am using a custom control ICCMDropdownlist and i have tried that.

Comment: @ Pomster You have to provide the code, how you created customcontrol. Otherwise its very difficult to give solution. Please update your question with code.